# Understanding how to replace a subset of hypotheses with a statement that is a valid conclusion of these hypotheses

Tags: logic

I am currently taking a course in Algebra and Discrete mathematics in my freshman year of college. I use the book *Algebra och diskret matematik av Johan Jonasson och Stefan Lemurell*. On page eighteen of this book one can read (now translated and shortened):

*If you want to show that an argument is valid, it is allowed to replace a subset of its hypotheses with a statement that is a valid conclusion of these hypotheses. Formally, this can be written as*

$$\dfrac{(H_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge H_i) \rightarrow B \qquad
(B \wedge H_{i+1} \wedge \cdots \wedge H_n) \rightarrow C}
{(H_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge H_n) \rightarrow C}$$

*Here the conclusion $(H_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge H_n) \rightarrow C$ is the original argument, $\{ H_1, \cdots, H_i \}$ is the subset of hypotheses and $B$ is the statement you prove from these.*

Not too much later they tell me that (in order) *$p$ is a valid conclusion drawn from the two hypotheses*

$\neg p \rightarrow q$

$\neg q.$

But I fail to see how these two hypotheses can "be simplified" or "give" $p$ as a valid conclusion. I suspect this partly stems from not fully understanding the formula I just gave you. Can you please help me understand? Note that I am a beginner in logic.

Comment: in English the mathematics word is Discrete. The other spelling, Discreet, is also a word, it means able to keep secrets.

Comment: @WillJagy thanks, I changed it.

Comment: You presumably have other rules that you can use. For example, if you have rules for the contrapositive and double negation elimination, you can show that $\neg p\to q\iff\neg q\to p$. Once you've done that, you can derive $p$ using the rule you mentioned in the case where $B=\neg q$, $C=p$, and $i=n=0$.